# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в выражении "смотреть() как на кумира"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Я смотрел на него(,) как на кумира".

Answer (score 2):

Нет, запятая перед КАК в данном случае не нужна. Это вовсе не сравнительный оборот.

Comment: ....
А что?

Comment: Здесь оборот с союзом КАК  имеет значение «в качестве». В таких случаях запятая не ставится.Если бы было значение причины, то запятую поставили бы.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятая перед КАК в данном случае не нужна, потому что сравнительный оборот имеет значение приравнивания или отождествления.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку возникли расхождения в в отнесении оборота к странительному, попробую навести порядок.

Есть подозрения, что запятая здесь действительно не нужна. Фраза, видимо, подпадает под случай "оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла".

Cравните:

*11.Миллионы людей совершали друг против друга такое бесчисленное количество злодеяний, обманов, измен, воровства, подделок и выпуска фальшивых ассигнаций, грабежей, поджогов и убийств, которого в целые века не соберет летопись всех судов мира и на которые, в этот период времени, люди, совершавшие их, не смотрели как на преступления (Толстой). 
--
Оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и имеет значение «в качестве» (без такого оборота сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла), поэтому запятую ставить не нужно.*

(см. http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что здесь, скорее всего, оборот имеет значение приравнивания, отождествления (ср.: "Вот почему она смотрела на землю как на юдоль скорби (А. Новиков-Прибой). 
(см. Н. С. Валгина "Трудные вопросы пунктуации")

Comment: А что тут чему приравнивается? 
Кумир в исходном значении всё-таки идол, божок - не подходит.
Остаётся "предмет обожания" - и вот тут возникает резонный вопрос, а как можно приравнять к предмету обожания - и как на него в таких случаях смотрят?

Comment: Запятая нужна была бы, если бы звучал, скажем, так: "Он смотрел на него так, как аборигены смотрят на своего кумира" - тут явное сравнение. В данном же случае речь о том, что он сделал кого-то своим кумиром и смотрел на него соответственно.

Comment: То, что запятая не нужна никто не возражает. Мне не нравится только ваше обоснование. Я не вижу тут приравнивания. Объект "смотрения",  судя по всему, и есть тот самый кумир для смотрящего. так чего тут приравнивать? При приравнивании всё-таки имеет место или переносный смысл или что-то нереальное.   
И уж совсем не понимаю как надо "соответственно" смотреть на кумира.
А запятая не нужна, никто не возражает.

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы правы насчёт "предмета обожания", но без полного контекста иногда бывает сложно судить о значении смысла. Вполне можно допустить, что кто-то на кого-то смотрел  "как на Бога".